# F450 frame all legs are not stable

Tags: quadcopters, drone-frame

I have one of the so called popular [F450 frames](https://st2.myideasoft.com/idea/bx/32/myassets/products/656/f450-frame-drone-frame-quadcopter-drone-govde.jpg?revision=1576164416). Not the original dji one, but chinese part. Now, I have assembled motors and ESCs. The assembling process was harder than it should be, probably because of not being original product. Anyway, I achieved to match holes with each other and installed the top plate. However, there is a problem. To cross legs(front left and rear right) cannot touch to the ground at the same time, i.e, one of the legs stay in the above the ground, approximately 2 cm. Is this something I should worry about? Can a neat flight be achieved with this problem existing?

Comment: Hi! Please attach a picture of what you're talking about, it's hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: @ifconfig i would like to, but, it is very hard to take a nice photo, because it is not easily visible. Let me express myself in a little bit shorter way. I assembled the frame, when I put it on a perfectly level ground, 3 of the legs are in contact with the ground but the fourth one is not touching to the ground, instead, hovering 1-2 cm above.

Comment: Right, but it's nearly impossible for us to understand what's happening without seeing it.

Comment: @ifconfig ok, just like restarting the computer can be a solution to many problems, I reassembled it and now it is fine. Thanks for your interest, you can delete the question when you see this comment.

Answer (score 4):

Do not worry, I also have an F450 frame(not original) and one or 2 of the legs stick up slightly. I have had a perfect flying experience even if I was using an Arduino as a Flight Controller. Your FC(Flight Controller) should smoothe it out. But, if it sticks up more than like 5cm, then you might have a slight concern.

Comment: I will be using my own flight controller, so things might go even worse than "arduino as fc" :D

Comment: Can you tell me more about your own flight controller? Like are you going to use an atmega chip or an stm32?

Comment: If you are using something in the Arduino family, you should check out Joop Broking's work. His work helped me fly my drone. And he in fact used a "Blue Pill" too.

Comment: But as per your question, it should be fine as long as you do your PID tuning correctly. If this is what you want please accept it as an answer!

Comment: I will be using blue pill, I am aware of Jopp Brokking, thanks for the advice. Different from his work, I will try not to use blue pill with arduino compatibility but as it is own register accesses, also no HAL or SPL. Gy-86 breakout board will serve as IMU. I also will not use commercial RC transmitters, instead 2x nRF24L01+ LNA/PA is what I will be using on both sides. Transmitter will also be based on bluepill.

Comment: Well, good luck on your project, and hope you don't face as many hardships I faced.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer as correct if you are satisfied?